# I have a list of arrays L and an array A. I need to find which array in L is the closest to A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, least-squares

As a part of a code, I have the following inputs:

- A list of arrays of dim NxM (L). This list can have between 100 and 300 arrays
- An input array of dim NxM (A)

I need to find which array Ln in L has the closest values to A by the least squares method (sum(Lnm-Anm)^2).

Initially I could run a for loop, calculate the norm between A and every single element in L and keep the one with the lowest norm afterwards, but I fear that this will be very inefficient. Is there any method, for example in Numpy or Scipy that could deal with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Numpy will be able to vectorize the comparisons so that the execution time will be smaller. But in general, any solution must calculate the norm between all the pairs to find the min.

Comment: Should investigate algorithms for that, there are some algorith that sort list by len(sub_lists), to be more efficients to find aproach match